# Myisam suport SET AUTOCOMMIT mode?

Tags: mysql

```
/* MyISAM */
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;

INSERT INTO table_name (table_field) VALUES ('foo');
INSERT INTO table_name (table_field) VALUES ('bar');

SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1
```

> Warning | 1196 | Some non-transactional changed tables couldn't be
>   rolled back

Myisam suport SET AUTOCOMMIT mode ?

Comment: myisam doesnt support transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyISAM effectively works in auto-commit mode (as it's not a transactional engine), and it just ignores the commit and Rollback.

Please visit this link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pluggable-storage-overview.html